# Тип переменной

Tags: c#

Скажите, вот у меня есть число 1**.**25, использовал double, так там надо так 1**,**25, а какой тип подойдет?

Comment: уточни вопрос, что тебе не нравится или что не получается в этом типе записи

Comment: мне прсто нужно число, где не будет точки... а можно будет и запятую использовать.

Answer (score 5):

Нужно использовать культуру и класс [NumberFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) для представления чисел с плавающей точкой в том или ином виде и с тем или иным разделителем.

Более подробно в статье [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

В статье [Culture Specific Number Formatting in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27053/Culture-Specific-Number-Formatting-in-ASP-NET) есть конкретные примеры.

Answer (score 3):

```
double number = 1.25;
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("G", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU")));
// на консоле выйдет 1,25
```

Есть и другие варианты, но неужели тяжело самому почитать на MSDN?

Comment: ну вот я почитала, везде примеры как в строку изменить. А мне нужно отправить число с точкой, а мое приложение отправляет с запятой (не меняя тип надо, то есть не в строку, а так же во флоат)

Answer (score 1):

ну и вопросы, используй double или float(double больше по своему диапазону), а вывод уже форматируй как хочешь, точка, запятая...

Comment: а можно пример?

Comment: а если не вывод, а само число нужно изменить, то тогда как?